# Filter multiple Content Search Web Parts with a refiner web part?

Tags: content-search-web-part, refiner, cswp

I have two Content Search web parts and a refiner web part on a web part page.

I would like one CSWP to display list items from one list and the other CSWP to display documents from a document library.

I then want to use the refiner web part to filter both CSWPs using managed metadata.

The key here is to filter multiple web parts on a page by managed metadata.

Is this possible to do? If it is, how can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We tried this a couple of years ago and out of the box there isn't a solutions (as far as I know.)

We did [try this solution](https://johanerixon.wordpress.com/2014/10/28/filtering-multiple-search-webparts-from-one-refinement-panel/). First you need a `result source` for both your library and list. Then you create a `query rule` that queries the first result source, say your document library, and then in the query rule you add a `result block` that passes the query onto the second result source. In the result block dialog you also give the block a label which the CSWP can use to pick up the results. Finally on the page you set up the CSWP to pick up the default (first part of the query) and another CSWP to pick up the result block.

After all that, the biggest downside is that you **can only send 10 items** in a result block. At least when we tried this several years ago that was the limit. So it ultimately was useless for us.

Is there a reason you can't use just one CSWP and mix the items and documents? You could add an item/document refiner.

Answer (score 0):

We also use the [same solution](https://johanerixon.wordpress.com/2014/10/28/filtering-multiple-search-webparts-from-one-refinement-panel/) to have one refiner to filter two other CSWP. 
Since we only want to show three results in each CSWP, it was not an issue for us in this case.

Here's the simplified steps, hope it helps.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this solution recommended by you and Rothrock. This works but the ideal solution wouldnt require the search box. Just now i have 2 web parts that display all the items then i just want to filter them, i dont want the user having to search first. Do you know if this is possible? by CSWP or another way?

Comment: @x48572 I might create custom view or do some javascript? Can you tell me more about the details about those two webparts and how would you like to filter them? :)